# How to use jqlite in angular to get a value of the attr

Tags: angularjs, jqlite

I whant to get the checked checkbox under the class"cer"  and the value of certid.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" class="cer" certid="ce.id" ><td>
```

How can i do it?

Comment: <td><input type="checkbox" class="cer" certid="ce.id" ></td>

Comment: is there any particular reason why you are not using models and values for this?

Comment: Are you using this on controller or directive ?

Comment: I want to use it in my controller